# How to use hyperbus driver file?

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, cypress, spi

I am so confused to understand hyperbus to communicate between Traveo II Body Evaluation Board to one hyperram, I read the datasheet (https://www.cypress.com/part/s27kl0641dabhi020) but still not understand how to implement example code. so for that, I search on google and I found this link (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/mtd/hyperbus/hyperbus-core.c) but not found any example code yet so anyone helps me or anyone provides the useful link or one example code?

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, [drivers/mtd/hyperbus/](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/mtd/hyperbus) implements hyperbus as a Memory Technology Device, also known as an MTD device; so, the hyperbus is accessed via the Linux MTD subsystem. [mtd-utils](http://git.infradead.org/mtd-utils.git) contains example code for accessing the MTD subsystem; see http://linux-mtd.infradead.org/ for further links.

The [Linux MTD hyperbus subsystem](http://linux-mtd.infradead.org/doc/general.html) exports a character device (/dev/mtd*N*).  An userspace application opens this device (read-write), then does an MEMGETINFO ioctl() to obtain the MTD device information into a `struct mtd_info_user` structure (defined in [<mtd/mtd-user.h>](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/mtd/mtd-user.h)). Operations to read, write, and erase blocks are done via ioctl()s (defined in [<mtd/mtd-abi.h>](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/mtd/mtd-abi.h)).  (On a Linux workstation, you'll find these in /usr/include/mtd/ if standard C development packages have been installed; on Debian derivatives, they're provided by the *linux-libc-dev* package.)

On these machines, Device Tree is used to describe the actual hardware, including hyperbus. You do not "configure" the hyperbus from the userspace when you open the character device; each hyperbus is described by a device tree blob (.dtb) or an overlay the kernel loads (or receives from the bootloader like uboot) at bootup.  I assume you already have the Device Tree etc. configured, since you are asking about how to use the character device; the character device(s) are created by the kernel from the Device Tree descriptions, and only show up if the hyperbus(es) have been configured.

Comment: thank you for your support, can you share example code (c or c++) with me? so I better understand hyperbus

Comment: Take a look at the [tests/mtd-tests/flash_speed.c](http://git.infradead.org/mtd-utils.git/blob/HEAD:/tests/mtd-tests/flash_speed.c).  Just clone the git repository, and compile all the tests; this one generates a Flash speed test you can run on an MTD device. You'll want to carefully understand how the core functions, [lib/libmtd.c:mtd_read()](http://git.infradead.org/mtd-utils.git/blob/HEAD:/lib/libmtd.c) et cetera, work.